# OutOfMemoryException with SQL query getting large amount of data from SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, out-of-memory

I am doing a migration, and I faced with a bad performance when I tried to get data from SQL server. The way that I do is:

```
ctx.ExampleEntity.Database.SQLQuery<ClassConverter>("Select....")
```

`ClassConverter` is a class that has no relation with the `ExampleEntity`. The problem is that I get more than 1.5 millions records from that query and when it tries to create the list, it throws a `OutOfMemoryException` and I am not able to avoid that.

It is the EF 6.0.

///////////////////////////////////Solution

Following the answer from Mayu, I have written this code, with 1M it doesn't throw the exception. The sql return the records that aren't in the final DB.

```
List<ClassConverter> listRowsToInsert = new List<ClassConverter>();
int countRecords=-1;
int skipCount = 0;
while(countRecords!=0){
   List<ClassConverter> listIndivInsert = genEntitAgp.Database.SqlQuery<ClassConverter>(File.ReadAllText("sql/limitPfm.sql")).Skip(skipCount).Take(1000000).ToList();
   countRecords = listIndivInsert.Count();
   listRowsToInsert.AddRange(listIndivInsert);
   if (countRecords < 1000000)
       countRecords = 0;
   skipCount += 1000000;
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks for all

Comment: Do you really need a million records at once?

Comment: Break the call down into batches?

Comment: If there's no relation, it might be returning a cross join, which means every row in one table is being associated with every row in the second table. If each table has 1000 rows, that's 1,000,000 rows returned. If you're not doing a join of any kind, and the table just has 1.5 million rows, you need to do a lazy fetch or fetch in batches, or filter better.

Comment: Have you turned off context tracking for your query? 
It looks like your sending a raw SQL statement, so not sure if it's possible in that scenario, but I'd guess that's whats hammering your memory. Also, as your using SQL Server, have you considered using Integration Services to perform the migration?

Comment: Do you use 64bit?

Comment: Yep Antonin I use 64 bits. I didn't consider Integration services indeed because it's complex migration, although I'll try to check it if it would be a posible option Eric. Related with if I need that records... Yep because that amount of it there aren't in the final

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using EF 6.0 can you map the entity and then process them in batches with `db.Records.Skip(n).Take(m)`?

Comment: This simple pagination has only one downside - you can get duplicated or missing records if data change.